# Salvar dados em um arquivo e recuperá-los com jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Quero simular um artigo de blog e salvar um comentário puramente por `Javascript`
então tenho 3 arquivos pra realizar essa tarefa:

```js
$("#enviar-comentario").click(function(){
 var nome = $("#nome").val();
 var mensagem = $("#mensagem").val();

 var msg = {
  nome: nome,
  mensagem: mensagem
 }
 var dados = {
  comentario: msg
 }
 $.post("http://127.0.0.1/edsa-direct/blog-inovacoes/js/comentarios", dados, function(){
  console.log("Enviei os dados");
 }).fail(function(){
  console.log("Não deu certo");
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="comentar col m8 s12 indigo lighten-5">
    <h5 class="center titulo-comentarios">Adicionar um comentário</h5>

    <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input id="nome" type="text" class="validate">
            <label for="nome">Nome</label>
          </div>

    <div class="input-field col s12">
       <textarea id="mensagem" class="materialize-textarea" maxlength="150"></textarea>
        <label for="mensagem">Mensagem</label>
    </div>

    <div class="center">
     <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" id="enviar-comentario">Comentar</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

E então, como visto na parte do js, eu envio para um arquivo chamado `comentarios` Que é um simplesmente um arquivo vazio. A requisição responde com sucesso, mas ao atualizar os dados não foram salvos lá!

O que fazer pra salvar os dados nesse arquivo?

Comment: Não entendi o que você realmente quer fazer.

Comment: Depois que o usuario preencher os 2 inputs, quero pegar os valores deles pela função do `jquery` e enviar por `ajax` `post` pra aquele arquivo vazio `comentarios` e salvar esse texto nele, pra posteriormente ser manipulado, só não sei como fazer isso. Não sei se precisa fazer alguma preparação naquele arquivo `comentarios`

Comment: Talvez haja solução melhor e mais simples para isso. Conhece `localStorage`?

Comment: Eu ia falar isso agora

Comment: Não conheço, mas é que fiz um curso de jquery e aprendi sobre o AJAX dentro dele. Porém no curso, salva-se as informações desta maneira e queria testar se sei fazer da mesma forma.

Comment: Creio que isto só seja possível apenas no IE utilizando ActiveX. :/

Comment: Tem alguma relação que o curso utilizou um servidor Node.js?

Comment: É provável, já que node.js roda no servidor. Mas não sei dizer com certeza.

Comment: Bem, então sem a outra ponta não tem como. O javascript sozinho não salva o arquivo, senão alguém poderia escrever o que quisesse dando um post para google.com por exemplo. Existe, no caminho que você passa os dados via post, um servidor interpretando um arquivo, que irá persistir esses dados em algum ponto.